# How do I write a build pre-action script in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift

I have successfully executed Swift code from the terminal and also from pre/post-triggers from an Xcode bot. But I am struggling to write a Swift script for a build pre-action. Has anyone managed this?

This is what my pre-action looks like:

[image]

When I build from terminal (`xcodebuild -scheme UAT build`) I see the following errors:

```
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:11:10: note: while building module 'Darwin' imported from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:11:  
#include <sys/types.h>  
^  
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "sys/cdefs.h"
^
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:707:2: error: Unsupported architecture
#error Unsupported architecture
^
```

**Update:**
If I just print something without importing the Foundation module then it works. I.e. `print("Hello")`. But I obviously can't use `NSProcessInfo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `--sdk` option of `xcrun` is set to `iPhoneOS` when building an iOS project. You need to explicitly state `--sdk macosx`.

Example:

[image: Edit scheme success]